# Slickgrid: how to get selected rows with new Checkbox Select Column plugin?

Tags: checkbox, multi-select, slickgrid

I am working with this example:
http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html

Looking inside checkboxselectolumn.js I can see a selectedRows  variable but this is empty to me it seems.

Any tips?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

bit of oo magic

grid.getSelectedRows();